# DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise

Tags: mongoose

I have this issue

```
(node:10372) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default
 promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: 
 http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

I tried this solves

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
```

Noone resolves this problem.

And with this issue I have another one problem - doesnt work decrement. `data.likes -= 1;`

Mongoose just doesnt save this! more precisely mongoose saves through time. I heard that this issue may be call by depreceted promises.

```
Post.findById(req.body._id, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}

    if (data.voited[req.session.id] == true) {
        data.voited[req.session.id] = false;
        data.likes += 1;
        var post = new Post(data);
        post.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send({status:416});
            } else {
                res.send({status:200, likes: true});
            }
        });
    } else {
        data.voited[req.session.id] = true;
        data.likes -= 1;
        var post = new Post(data);
        post.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send({status:416});
            } else {
                res.send({status:200, likes: false});
            }
        });
    }   
})
```

What to do? Delete mongoose? I wouldnt like rewrite all project..

mongoose 4.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the `Promise` before connecting?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://...');
```

Also make sure you set the `Promise` whenever you use mongoose, even on your `Schema`.

As mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4291).

**EDIT**: About the decrement issue (which I believe is related to the previous if you're not using promises anywhere else). Try this.

```
Post.findById(req.body._id, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}

    var session = data.voited[req.session.id];

    if (session == true) {
       Post.update({_id: req.body._id}, {$inc: {likes: 1}, voited: {[req.session.id]: false}}, function(err, data) {
          if (err) { console.log(err); }
          res.send({ status:200, likes: true });
          });  
    } else {
        Post.update({_id: req.body._id}, {$inc: {likes: -1}, voited: {[req.session.id]: true}}, function(err, data) {
           if (err) { console.log(err); }
           res.send({ status:200, likes: false });
        });
    }   
 });
```

Comment: Yes, before. Problem was solved. I set `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` in Schema but decrement still is not working. Do you know about it?

Comment: Just edited my initial answer.
Unless you are using promises anywhere else in your code I think the issues are actually related. And if removing `new Post(data)` fixed your issue you could also safely remove the previously added `mongoose.Promise` declarations.
That being said there's also no harm in keeping it if you are to ever use promises.

Comment: Just noticed that on the [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4291) there's a note about save always returning a promise (even if a callback is provided). So you should actually keep the `mongoose.Promise` declarations.

Comment: I tried this code and `post.voited[req.session.id] = false;` doesnt save but 
        `post.likes += 1;` saves. May be because one object another number types.  `if(){} ` checks `post.voited[req.session.id] == true` and it needs save too. Now I will try to do this.